# MVC Foolproof Validation RequiredIfFalse returning error incorrectly

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, foolproof-validation

I'm using the MVC Foolproof Validation library to make dependent requirements:

```
public bool IsRequired { get; set; }
[RequiredIfTrue("IsRequired", ErrorMessage = "This field is required")]
public int RequiredIfTrueSelectID { get; set; }
```

This works perfectly on the client side, allowing me to submit the form without a `RequiredIfTrueSelectID` value (i.e. value is 0), but on the `[HttpPost]` the `ModelState.IsValid` returns false, and with the following result in the immediate window:

```
myViewModel.IsRequired 
   true
ModelState["RequiredIfTrueSelectID"].Errors[0]
  {System.Web.Mvc.ModelError}
    ErrorMessage: "A value is required."
    Exception: null
```

I'm ensuring that I'm posting back the value of RequiredIfTrueSelectID (as you can see in the first immediate window query above). Why am I getting the "A value is required" message, and how can I suppress this error?

By the way, I'm in MVC5. Maybe the `ModelState` implementation has changed since Foolproof's last update 2 years ago? Does anyone else know of a more recently-published library that functions like Foolproof?

Controller method:

```
[HttpPost]
public virtual ActionResult ValidationTest(TestViewModel vm)
{ //breakpoint here to check ModelState.IsValid
    return View(vm); 
}
```

Comment: Are you manually changing the value of AllowAnyPlan from the actual posted value?

Comment: @ErikFunkenbusch no. I'm setting a breakpoint at the opening brace of my controller method

Comment: @ErikFunkenbusch I even tried changing `AllowAnyPlan` to be readonly as `true` and it still happens

Comment: I found that if I retrigger the validation `ModelState.Clear(); ValidateModel(myViewModel);` it works correctly, so that's a workaround for now, but I don't want to have to call this every time

Comment: What is ValidateModel?  Do you mean UpdateModel?

Comment: `ValidateModel()` on the controller: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.validatemodel(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: Right, brain freeze.   What does your controller method look like, including the parameters?

Comment: I've updated the question to show my controller method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oh, duh.  Your field is a value type.

Value types are always required.  You need to make the type nullable if you want it to be optional.

Notice that the error message is not the same as the error message used in your validator, that's the first clue.

Comment: Ah, that explains it! I'm still new to MVC, so I didn't know about that. Changing it to `int?` and intializing the value to 0 gives me the results I needed. Although I will have to add some `??` to everything back to `int`s, but that's okay. Thanks!

Comment: Actually, this is giving me a problem. the value now gets `null` as a default value, which screws up the binding on my dropdown after a postback. I initialize the value to 0 in the model constructor, but after a postback it gets set to `null`, so my dropdown shows nothing instead of the first item in the dropdown. any insight?

Comment: @DLeh - 0 satisfies required, you can't have a value and use required.. so if your code requires there to be a value, but you want the value to be optional, you have a dilemma to figure out.  It sounds like what you really want is "zero if true" not "required if true"

Comment: I guess I'm hoping for "Allow zero if false", or "Disallow zero if true". Also, since I am using this in a dropdown, 0 doesn't seem to satisfy required. Which is what I want, conditionally.

Comment: Anyway, I can just detect the `null` value in the dropdown and replace it with javascript to be 0. I'm doubting that the "allow or disallow zero" will be achievable. Thanks again for the help!

Comment: @DLeh - you probably shouldn't be using a 0 value for a default anyways, you should be using the null value for default and using the default option parameter of the DropDownListFor to set the text that displays for this.

Comment: That is what I'm doing. The default option doesn't show when `null` is provided though, it just shows a blank entry that disappears once another value is selected, and the "Any" entry shows underneath that. I want that entry to be selected by default. Setting the dropdown value to null is different than setting it to `0` or `''`, apparently. Basically, I want everything that it does normally with a `0` except be able to mark it as invalid in a certain situation.

Comment: @DLeh - No, there is a paremeter called "optionLabel", which is displayed when the value is null.  This would be for your "Select a value" or "Any" or whatever you want for the default.  You don't use a value of 0.

Comment: Hm, okay maybe I'm thinking of a different parameter. I'll look into that. Thanks!